# objective C - how to replace all words of a sentence with another word

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

Suppose I have this sentence

"Hello, my name is Betty!"

I need to replace all words with 3 or more letters with the word "thing", while retaining capitalization and punctuation. What is the best way to do this in Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with simple counter to count the amount of letters that end with space,period or any other char. That will be my current words length.

When you know the amount of letters that your new string will use
You do another pass and simply copy the shorter ones and replace the longer ones(also with the help of a counter) with the word "thing".

You could also keep a track of the positions and length of words that are longer, but that is not necessary.